# how slider resize font in JtextArea?

Tags: java, swing

I use Java swing, I want to resize my font in JtextAre using slider, but, I don't know how to start. This is my picture planning.
[image]

Comment: *"I don't know how to start."* Break it down into small steps. E.G. start with the [`JSlider` tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html).

Comment: Thank for your help @Andrew Thompson. I know what I have to do after that

Answer (score 4):

As you already seem to know how to set up the components, the required task is to merely add a fitting `ChangeListener` to your `JSlider`, that can control the font size in your `JTextArea`.

- Your slider should be set up in a way, so that its resulting values make sense as font sizes. (In the example, I chose the values between 10-30).
- The `ChangeListener` should get the newly selected value of your `JSlider`, and then set the font size accordingly.

For reference on the `JSlider`, check out the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html).

Here is a small working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> buildGui());
}

private static void buildGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    // set default font size to 10 to match JSlider starting position
    textArea.setFont(new Font(textArea.getFont().getName(), textArea.getFont().getStyle(), 10));
    frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // set up slider
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 10, 30, 10);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    // create and add change listener
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int fontSize = slider.getValue();
            Font currentFont = textArea.getFont();
            // get the current font and set the modified font size
            textArea.setFont(new Font(currentFont.getName(), currentFont.getStyle(), fontSize));
        }
    });

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Result:

[image: Result 1]

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Thank for your help @maloomeister. It's great, I know what I have to do after that, because I have some trouble to find solution. I'm a beginner for Java swing.